# How to write properly table name in dbGetQuery function?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I have an issue of specifying table name in dbGetQuery function.

The command

```
data1 <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from bank_schema.capital")
```

works well.

But the command

```
data1 <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from bank_schema.135_ratios")
```

throws an error.

Where con is connection object to postgreSQL database.

Please, help me to find way out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres by default does not support table names that start with digits (other RDBMS have the same limitation). You would need to quote the table name. Consider:

```
data1 <- dbGetQuery(con, 'select * from bank_schema."135_ratios"')
```

Or:

```
data1 <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from bank_schema.\"135_ratios\"")
```

But better yet, it would be simpler to rename the table to something more standard (ie that does not start with a digit), for example `ratios_135`.

Comment: Done. Thank you. Can I ask you another question concerning with SQL? If YES how can connect with you?

Comment: @DavidBijoyan: you can just [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on the site...

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote identifier with `"`:

```
data1 <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from bank_schema.\"135_ratios\"")
```